# Use same variable in filter() and map() of a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-8, java-stream

To improve performance I want to use the same variable in both `filter()` and `map()` of a Java 8 stream.
Example-

```
                list.stream()
                .filter(var -> getAnotherObject(var).isPresent())
                .map(var -> getAnotherObject(var).get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The called method `getAnotherObject()` looks like-

```
private Optional<String> getAnotherObject(String var)
```

In the above scenario I have to call the method `getAnotherObject()` twice.
If I go with a regular *for loop* then I have to call the method `getAnotherObject()` only once.

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String var : list) {
            Optional<String> optionalAnotherObject = getAnotherObject(var);
            if(optionalAnotherObject.isPresent()) {
                String anotherObject = optionalAnotherObject.get();
                resultList.add(anotherObject)
            }
        }
```

Even with stream I can put all my code in `map()`-

```
list.stream()
                .map(var -> {
                    Optional<String> anotherObjectOptional = getAnotherObject(var);
                    if(anotherObjectOptional.isPresent()) {
                        return anotherObjectOptional.get();
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I believe there must be an *elegant* way using `filter()`.

Comment: `list.stream().map(var -> getAnotherObject(var)).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());` (untested, I just can't see why that wouldn't work off the top of my head).

Comment: Did you get a lot of performance improvement from the solution?

Comment: Your last approach is not bad. Just replace `if(anotherObjectOptional.isPresent()) {
                        return anotherObjectOptional.get();
                    }
                    return null;` with `.orElse(null)`. In other words, simplify the entire step to `.map(var -> getAnotherObject(var).orElse(null) .filter(Objects::nonNull)`. In Java 9, you can simply use `.flatMap(var -> getAnotherObject(var).stream())`

Comment: @Kayaman: If the method `getAnotherObject()` was doing some heavyweight process then its surely worth avoiding the second call + Its just bad practice to call the same method twice for same purpose!

Comment: @Holger : That's indeed an elegant solution avoiding the `map()` chains....i'll give it a try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a stream like this

```
list.stream()
        .map(YourClass::getAnotherObject)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

YourClass refer to the  name of the class where `getAnotherObject` method is defined

Comment: This would result in a `List<Optional<T>>`.  The code they provided results in a `List<T>`.  (Not saying that's not an easy resolution...  Just a difference in behaviour.) Edit has resolved this +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flatMap`. Usually this is used to flatten stuff, but here you can

1. map the element to that element if the optional has a value
2. map the element to an empty stream if the optional has no value

Like this:

```
stream
    .map(x -> getAnotherObject(x))
    .flatMap(x -> x.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.of())))
```